# Java 3D Documentation

Tags: java, api, 3d, game-engine, java-3d

I have now installed Java 3D API and there a many, I think, useful classes, but I have no idea, which constructors they have and which methods you can call on them so I wondered if there is a way to look them up?

Is there a good Documentation for Java 3D? If searched on Google and found this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/, but there is only all the stuff of the "core" listed and not the "utils"?

Or maybe you could give me a good and easy alternative library/Api similar to Java 3D?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I have added my problem is it now clear why I'm asking for a Documentation?

Comment: It is still off-site content and therefore off-topic. If you found the library, you should be able to find a tutorial for this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (JogAmp Java3D maintainers) haven't uploaded the Java3D API documentation of the very latest pre-version (currently 1.6.0 pre12) yet, sorry:
http://forum.jogamp.org/Java3D-1-6-0-online-API-documentation-td4031621.html

Are you sure that you use the latest version? Have you followed my instructions?
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D

Just a reminder, Java3D has been maintained for several years by the JogAmp community after Oracle/Sun Microsystems gave it up.

As the public API has remained mostly unchanged, you can go on using the "old" documentation in the meantime even though Harvey and me will have to upload the very latest documentation later.